# Create more than 1 advanced topic types

Tags: nodes

I have a **content type** called advanced forum topic, which is created from the [Advanced Forum module](https://drupal.org/project/advanced_forum).

I would like to have 3 different kinds of topics(General, Player, Team).
Each of this has different fields. My thought was to organize these into **Field collections**. Is there a way that I can choose the topic type with a dropdown menu and then the rest of the fields in the collection would pop up dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do your requirement with [Conditional Fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module. You can show different fields depend on the select list of topics.

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between
> fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for
> editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the
> right condition.
>
> When editing a node (or any other entity type that
> supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are
> dynamically modified with the States API.